# How to create values of my presonal defined data type in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I have created a data type that is a bit more complex. The data type is below:

```haskell
data MyData = Var String | Con Bool |  Two TwoOp MyData MyData | List [MyData]
 deriving Show

data TwoOp = And | Or deriving Show
```

My problem is the following: givent two values of "MyData" type how can i use the constructors Two, TwoOp to build a new value of "MyData" :

```haskell
Two TwoOp MyData MyData
```

Thanks in advace!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will provide an answer in terms of using the interactive interpreter GHCi

putting your definitions in a file `MyFile.hs`

```
module MyFile where

data MyData = Var String
            | Con Bool
            | Two TwoOp MyData MyData
            | List [MyData]
            deriving Show
data TwoOp = And
           | Or
           deriving Show
```

now loading this into GHCi

```
$> ghci MyFile.hs
GHCi, version 7.10.3: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
[1 of 1] Compiling MyFile           ( MyFile.hs, interpreted )
Ok, modules loaded: MyFile.
*MyFile> let a = Var "test"
*MyFile> let true = Con True
*MyFile> let false = Con False
*MyFile> a
Var "test"
*MyFile> true
Con True
*MyFile> false
Con False
*MyFile> Two And a true
Two And (Var "test") (Con True)
*MyFile> List [a,true,false, Var "this is also a test"]
List [Var "test",Con True,Con False,Var "this is also a test"]
```

**Note:** You do not need the `let` keywords if you are using the constructors (top-level) inside a file.

```
module MyFile where

...

testdata :: Mydata
testdata = Two And (Var "x") (Con False)
```

### Update:

But honestly writing testdata by hand is more than a bit tedious using `SmallCheck` this can be done by your computer, only with slight modifications of your file - note you can start using this, and learn the backgrounds for it later if you are a beginner. The [documentation](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/smallcheck) is a good starting point.

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveGeneric #-}

module MyFile where

import Test.SmallCheck.Series
import GHC.Generics

data MyData = Var String
            | Con Bool
            | Two TwoOp MyData MyData
            | List [MyData]
            deriving(Show, Generic)

instance Monad m => Serial m MyData

data TwoOp = And
           | Or
           deriving(Show, Generic)

instance Monad m => Serial m TwoOp
```

**Note:** you need to put `smallcheck` in your cabal file in `build-depends`or `cabal install smallcheck` globally for that.

Then `cabal repl` or `ghci MyFile.hs` (or `stack ghci`) should load the file into the interpreter.

```
$> stack ghci
Configuring GHCi with the following packages: generate
GHCi, version 7.10.3: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
[1 of 1] Compiling MyFile           ( MyFile.hs, interpreted )
Ok, modules loaded: MyFile.
*MyFile MyFile> import Test.SmallCheck.Series
*MyFile MyFile Test.SmallCheck.Series> randomData <- listM 3 (series :: Series IO MyData)
*MyFile MyFile Test.SmallCheck.Series> length randomData
38
*MyFile MyFile Test.SmallCheck.Series> mapM_ print randomData
Var ""
Two And (Var "") (Var "")
Con True
List []
Var "a"
Two Or (Var "") (Var "")
Con False
Two And (List []) (Var "")
Var "b"
Two Or (List []) (Var "")
Two And (Var "") (List [])
Two Or (Var "") (List [])
Two And (Con True) (Var "")
...
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the *value* constructors to construct values. Value constructors are those identifiers found after `data .. =` and after every successive `|`.

In your case, the value constructors are `Var, Con, Two, List` doe type `MyData`, and `And, Or` for type `TwoOp`.

E.g.

```
Two And (Con True) (Var "x")
```